# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\infty[}\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{3n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\infty[}\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{3n}}}d\lambda$

does it converge or diverge?

I know I have the $3$ following options but have not been fruitful thus far:

**monotone convergence**
I cannot prove that $f_{n}(x)$ is monotone for all $x \in [0,\infty[$.

**dominating convergence** here I am looking at the following:
$\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{3n}}}\leq\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ which does not help me at all as $\frac{1}{x^2} \notin \mathcal{L}^{1}(\lambda)$. Neither does for $x>1$, $\frac{1}{x}\geq\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}}\geq\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{3n}}}$

My last hope is

**Fatou's Lemma**
but $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\infty[}\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{3n}}}d\lambda \geq\int_{[0,\infty[}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{3n}}}d\lambda$ and nothing meaningful comes out of this either.

Comment: $\lambda$ or $x$ ?

Answer (score 4):

The dominated convergence theorem is indeed useful here, but with a better dominating function. Note that $x^{-2}$ is indeed integrable on $[1, \infty)$. On the other hand,

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1 + x^{3n}}} \le x$$

for all $x \ge 0$, so you have the (rather efficient) bound

$$0 \le \frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1 + x^{3n}}} \le x \chi_{[0, 1]}(x) + x^{-2} \chi_{[1, \infty)}(x)$$

which is good enough.

Comment: Here's the key takeaway: If you have a dominating function that's *almost* good enough except for a little singularity... try modifying it to get a bounded one instead.